# autoinstall ubuntu 22.04 LTS autoinstall does not work in uefi mode

Tags: uefi, pxe, user-data, autoinstall

I'm working on autoinstall ubuntu 22 for my company (using VMWare and PXE). It works fine with legacy configs, but not with UEFI.
I have continued the install process to the end and then get the autoinstall file to compare with mine. I tried too, to replace my user-data file with the generated one. But the result is always the same. The interactive installer is always starting and I can't succeed in getting my server installed automatically when booting UEFI.
The result is the same if I completely remove the storage section of my file.

Can you help me ?
Regards

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So you're trying to install Ubuntu Core 22 (the *year* format for products is used to highlight different products, ie. 22 & 22.04 are different systems, 22 being a *flavor* of 22.04 Server).

Comment: Sorry, it's 22.04 version.

Comment: Please correct your question then; Ubuntu 22.04 & Ubuntu Core 22 are different products; & being specific matters. *Also be specific as to which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're using, as multiple installers are available, and they have differences*

Comment: I finally solved the problem. 
It was in the grub.cfg append boot line. The option ds='nocloud-net;s=http://<my_web_server>/' needs quotes to works with uefi.
But seems to work fine without quotes in legacy mode.